# My webpack doesn't implement SVG inline, only like url

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpack-5

webpack config

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-svg-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
        filename: 'build/[name].budle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/template.html'),
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin({
            runPreEmit: true,
            inlineAll: true,
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/source',
            },
        ],
    },
    watch: true,
}
```

JS

```
    const imgCar = document.createElement('img')
    imgCar.setAttribute('src', carSvg)
    imgCar.classList.add('car-img')
    carBtnsMove.appendChild(imgCar)
```

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I am trying do this is pure js, I don't know where is problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `carSvg` contains what you want. So write that. Don't bother with the `imgCar`. IOW, `carBtnsMove.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', carSvg)`.

Comment: You've added the `img` tag, why do you expect it to be `svg`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's work! However when i try chnage collor like this : `carSvg.style.fill = '#333333'`  i get a error  "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'fill')" why?